# Doxygen including DLL-SourceCode

Tags: c#, dll, doxygen

Im trying to document a project with doxygen. The project consists of multiple libraries which are all generated and developed in a single project.

I want Doxygen to document the project as a single source code so I want callgraphs follow the DLLs and put them together. Is this possible?

Comment: When I do understand it correctly you have a number of directories each giving their own dll. There are a few possibilities: - brute force document all in one go, so specify all directories in the `INPUT` tag - use TAG files, (see `GENERATE_TAGFILE` and `GENERATE_TAGFILE` in the configuration file and the documentation). Might be that you have to run twice, first to generate the TAGFILEs and in the second run the documentation. I don't know, by head, how this will work out on the call graphs though (might be necessary to do some experiments and remove the call graphs between the 2 runs).

Comment: I tested but got two solutions which are both not "the way" I want it.
Using a tagfile didnt make any callgraphs at all. Using ALLEXTERNALS in addition gave me the callgraphs as I wanted them, but it included WAY too much external stuff from other libs which are not under my development

Comment: This implies a bit, as far as I can see, that you should tune the Doxyfile of the different project parts so the individual parts are so as you would like them and combine then the different outputs by means of the TAGFILEs.